# BitmapFactory.Options returns 0 width and height

Tags: android, bitmap

```java
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
```

**`path` is the image file path which is proper.**

The problem is `options.outHeight` and `options.outWidth` are **0** when the image is captured in **Landscape** mode with **AutoRotate on**. If I turn off **AutoRotate**, it works fine. Since its width and height are 0 I was getting a null `Bitmap` at the end.

**Complete Code:**

```
Bitmap photo = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(filePath, DESIRED_WIDTH,
                    DESIRED_HEIGHT);
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;
    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    }
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: even am facing the same issue.did you find any work around on it ?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by changing :

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

to:

```
try {
    InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                       Uri.parse(path));
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // do something
}
```

After that change, the width and height were correctly set.